# Check the duplicate element in an array using set in python

Tags: python, list, set, repeat, find-occurrences

Scan and check the numbers in an array if it is repeated, if true print yes, else print no
So what I'm trying to do is convert them into a set (and list)

```
a = [int(v) for v in input().split()]
b = set(a)
```

and check if the occurrence of an element in list a is equal to that is set b, but currently, there's no such function to count the occurrence in set b, isn't it? I'm dumb so pls help

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a.count(a[i]) == ..occurrence in set b..:
        print("NO")
    else:
        print("YES")
```

example input:

```
1 2 3 2 3 4
```

output:

```
NO
NO
NO
YES
YES
NO
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I understand. What do you mean by "count the occurrence in set b"? If b is a set there are no repetitions by definition. Can you make your problem clearer ?

Comment: By looking at the output it seems that you want to check if an element was already seen

Answer (score 0):

Given the problem description you need a code that identifies if an item of a list appears in it more than once. Here's one way you can do it,

```
from collections import Counter

# Input list with duplicates
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]

# Count of each list element
counted_numbers = Counter(numbers)

# Chech occurrence of each list element
for el in numbers:
    if counted_numbers[el] > 1:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')
```

The code uses `Counter` to create a dictionary with number of occurrences of each list element. In other words, `counted_numbers` are a dictionary where the keys are unique elements of the list `numbers` and the values are the number of times they appear in the list.

The second part of the code loops through the original list and checks how many times it appears as reported by `Counter`. If its more than one, it prints `YES`.

Temporary note: the output is different than in your example, let me know if this is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in a[:i]:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

If the number at index is appeared on the left hand side of the current index, it is printed YES, otherwise NO.

Comment: Please, if one of the answers solved your problem, remember to accept it by toggling the check mark besides it. See [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```py
count = set()
for num in nums:
    if num in count:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
   count.add(num)
```

Comment: What is nums by the way python is having problem with it

Comment: oh nums is just the name of the list you nums should be whatever your list is called